# ucwa get more than 100 search result

Tags: lync, skype-for-business, ucwa

How can i get more than 100 search request result with SFB ucwa?

I tried to search all contacts, which contain my domain, but in response i got only 100 first contacts. How can i find second page or exceed query limit?

I send this GET request:

https://lync.myDomain.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/897843985443/people/search?query=[myDomain]&limit=100

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the API is designed for that, and UCWA doesn't support pagination / OData consistently.

That method is designed indeed to return up to 100 items, and provide a 'refine your search' experience to be implemented, for instance, in your custom client to provide 'search for contacts' capability

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know any methods to get all contacts of my domain? Or it is impossible?

Comment: Not that I know of in UCWA, and as I said I think it isn't designed for that. We used to maintain a list of users in a DB. You have different options depending also on your infrastructure: query AD via LDAP (on-prem), use Unified or Azure AD Graph API (O365), or make use of EWS (for either on-prem or 365)